# SwiftUI Index out of range in ForEach

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

After hours of debugging I figured out the error is inside the foreach loop in `MenuItemView` in the folder `ContentViews`.

The app crashes and the error is:

> `Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444`.

**Information:**

I have got an `ObservableObject`  with an `Array` of `Structs` inside as data storage.

**The problem:**

The ForEach goes between 0 and the array count + 1. This is so I can have an extra item for adding new elements. In the ForEach is a check if the index is inside the bounds (`if (idx >= palettesOO.palettes.count)` then show the plus).

But it crashes when I right click any cell and click "Remove". This calls the function `RemovePalette` in the class `Manager`. There the data gets removed from the array inside the `ObservableObject` - this also works.

AFTER the function gets called the app crashes (I know this because I printed a message after the function call). I figured out that the crash occurs when the view gets redrawn (updated).

If I have a view element which does not need a binding, for example a `Text`, then it works, if it needs a binding, for example a `TextField` it crashes. `Text(palettesOO.palettes[idx].palName)` inside of the else inside the ForEach works but view elements or subviews which require Bindings do not work: `TextField("", text: $palettesOO.palettes[idx].palName)` crashes.

I have tried modifying the ForEach with things like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59060673/swiftui-foreach-index-out-of-range-error-when-removing-row) but with no success.

**The Code and Data:**

```swift
class PalettesOO: ObservableObject {
    @Published var palettes = [Palette]()
}
```

**MenuItemView:**

```swift
struct MenuItemView: View {
    @ObservedObject var palettesOO = PalettesOO()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SectionView("Palettes") {
                LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.fixed(viewCellSize), spacing: viewCellSpacing), count: viewColCount), spacing: viewCellSpacing) {
                    ForEach(0..<palettesOO.palettes.count + 1, id: \.self) { idx in
                        if (idx >= palettesOO.palettes.count) {
                            Button(action: {
                                newPalettePopover = true
                            }, label: {
                                Image(systemName: "plus.square").font(.system(size: viewCellSize))
                            }).buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        }
                        else {
                            // Works
                            Text(palettesOO.palettes[idx].palName)
                            // Does not work
                            TextField("ASD", text: $palettesOO.palettes[palettesOO.palettes.count - 1].palName).frame(width: 100, height: 100).background(Color.red).contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
                                Button(action: {}, label: {
                                    Text("Rename")
                                })
                            Button(action: { Manager.RemovePalette(name: palettesOO.palettes[idx].palName); print("Len \(palettesOO.palettes.count)") }, label: {
                                    Text("Delete")
                                })
                            }))
                            // Original code, also crashes (PalettePreviewView is a custom subview which does not matter for this)
//                            PalettePreviewView(palette: $palettesOO.palettes[palettesOO.palettes.count - 1], colNum: $previewColCount, cellSize: $viewCellSize).cornerRadius(viewCellSize / 100 * viewCellRadius).contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
//                                    Button(action: {}, label: {
//                                        Text("Rename")
//                                    })
//                                Button(action: { Manager.RemovePalette(name: palettesOO.palettes[idx].palName); print("Len \(palettesOO.palettes.count)") }, label: {
//                                        Text("Delete")
//                                    })
//                                }))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.padding().fixedSize()
    }
}
```

**Manager:**

```swift
class Manager {
    static func RemovePalette(name: String) {
        var url = assetFilesDirectory(name: "Palettes", shouldCreate: true)
        url?.appendPathComponent("\(name).json")
        if (url == nil) {
            return
        }

        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url!)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error: \(error.domain)")
        }
        LoadAllPalettes()
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "\(k_paletteIndicies).\(name)")
    }
}
```

I know that such complex problems are not good to post on Stack Overflow but I can't think of any other way.

The project version control is public on my [GitHub](https://github.com/MarioMatschgi/MenuColorPalettes), in case it's needed to find a solution.

EDIT 12/21/2020 @ 8:30pm:
Thanks to @SHS it now works like a charm!
Here is the final working code:

```
struct MenuItemView: View {
    @ObservedObject var palettesOO = PalettesOO()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ...
            ForEach(0..<palettesOO.palettes.count + 1, id: \.self) { idx in
                ...
                ////  @SHS Changed :-
                Safe(self.$palettesOO.palettes, index: idx) { binding in
                    TextField("ASD", text: binding.palName).frame(width: 100, height: 100).background(Color.red).contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
                        Button(action: {}, label: {
                            Text("Rename")
                        })
                        Button(action: { Manager.RemovePalette(name: binding.wrappedValue.palName); print("Len \(palettesOO.palettes.count)") }, label: {
                            Text("Delete")
                        })
                    }))
                }
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}

////  @SHS Added :-
//// You may keep the following structure in different file or Utility folder. You may rename it properly.
struct Safe<T: RandomAccessCollection & MutableCollection, C: View>: View {
    
    typealias BoundElement = Binding<T.Element>
    private let binding: BoundElement
    private let content: (BoundElement) -> C
    
    init(_ binding: Binding<T>, index: T.Index, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (BoundElement) -> C) {
        self.content = content
        self.binding = .init(get: { binding.wrappedValue[index] },
                             set: { binding.wrappedValue[index] = $0 })
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        content(binding)
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of help are you seeking if you are not going to show lines of code?  If you try to delete a record inside the ForEach loop, obviously, the app will crash, anyway.

Comment: I can't show the code here because that would be to much and the problem is too complex for that, I'm sorry. But the code is on my [GitHub](https://github.com/MarioMatschgi/MenuColorPalettes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [Answer at stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63083658/2641380)

Create a struct as under

```
struct Safe<T: RandomAccessCollection & MutableCollection, C: View>: View {
   
   typealias BoundElement = Binding<T.Element>
   private let binding: BoundElement
   private let content: (BoundElement) -> C

   init(_ binding: Binding<T>, index: T.Index, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (BoundElement) -> C) {
      self.content = content
      self.binding = .init(get: { binding.wrappedValue[index] },
                           set: { binding.wrappedValue[index] = $0 })
   }
   
   var body: some View {
      content(binding)
   }
}
```

Then wrap your code for accessing it as under

```
Safe(self.$palettesOO.palettes, index: idx) { binding in
    //Text(binding.wrappedValue.palName)
    TextField("ASD", text: binding.palName)
    //TextField("ASD", text: $palettesOO.palettes[palettesOO.palettes.count - 1].palName)
       .frame(width: 100, height: 100).background(Color.red)
       .contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
             Button(action: {}, label: {
                 Text("Rename")
             })
             Button(action: { Manager.RemovePalette(name: binding.wrappedValue.palName); print("Len \(palettesOO.palettes.count)") }, label: {
                 Text("Delete")
             })
       }))
    }
```

I hope this can help you ( till it is corrected in Swift )

Comment: I have tried to implement what you suggested but it did not work for me, I updated my question with the code I tried it with

Comment: @MarioElsnig I have emailed you 'MenuItemView.swift'. Please take a look at it.

Comment: I've just tried it and it worked, thank you so much for your patience!